# Post Multipart/Form-Data Failing, corrupt form data: premature ending

Tags: excel, http-post, multipartform-data, boundary, vba

I'm getting an error code that I cannot figure out!  In my vba I am creating an excel file and uploading it to a server using POST.  I can manually import this file no problem, but for some reason my code is getting a failure response from the server - code 415, corrupt form data: premature ending.

```
Sub offline_punch()

Dim newwkb As Workbook
Dim thiswkb As Workbook
Dim URLReportop As String
Dim myrequestop As Object
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range

Set thiswkb = ActiveWorkbook
Set StartCell = thiswkb.Worksheets("offline_punch").Range("A1")
Set newwkb = Workbooks.Add


'Find LastRow and LastColumn
LastRow = thiswkb.Worksheets("offline_punch").Cells(thiswkb.Worksheets("offline_punch").Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = thiswkb.Worksheets("offline_punch").Cells(StartCell.Row, thiswkb.Worksheets("offline_punch").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
thiswkb.Worksheets("offline_punch").Range(StartCell, thiswkb.Worksheets("offline_punch").Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Copy
newwkb.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
newwkb.SaveAs ("E:\Documents\PunchImport" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmddhhmmss") & ".xls"), 56
thiswkb.Activate
Call getToken

'Send raw punch import to wfr
Set myrequestop = CreateObject("winhttp.winhttprequest.5.1")
URLReportop = ("https://secure.saashr.com:443/ta/rest/v1/import/119")
myrequestop.Open "POST", URLReportop, False
myrequestop.setRequestHeader "Authentication", "Bearer " & Token
myrequestop.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=abcdefghi-jklmnop; charset=UTF-8"
myrequestop.setRequestHeader "Content-length", 1000
myrequestop.Send newwkb

MsgBox (myrequestop.responseText & " " & Now)

newwkb.Close
Set newwkb = Nothing
thiswkb.Activate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - Add code for using correct file length

At top of sub add:

```
Dim strFilename     As String
Dim lngFileLen      as Long
```

Change your call to `newwkb.SaveAs` to these three lines

```
strFilename = "E:\Documents\PunchImport" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmddhhmmss") & ".xls"
newwkb.SaveAs (strFilename), 56
lngFileLen = FileLen(strFilename)
```

Change this line

```
myrequestop.setRequestHeader "Content-length", 1000
```

To this

```
myrequestop.setRequestHeader "Content-length", lngFileLen
```

Comment: without that line, I get the same error unfortunately

Comment: Yes - but it has to be correct. I'll update my post with code

Comment: Personally I'd also prefer closing the workbook before you do all the sending stuff. It'll guarantee correct file size and remove any possibility of cached changes or possible locks on file. I'd move the close wb line `newwkb.Close` tojust after `Call getToken`